# what is this function called

Tags: functions, terminology

There's a function that I graphed in class but I have no idea what it's called. I tried looking up things like "sickle-shaped function graph" and "function that is an absolute value and a quadratic," but I got nothing. None of my classmates know it either.

[image: mystery function]

Comment: There's no reason for it to have a special name!  It's just an absolute value function plus an exponential function plus a constant function.  To understand why it has the shape that it has, it might be worth plotting the three pieces independently ($-|x+3|$, $2^x$, and $-4$).  (By the way, not everything that turns upward like that is quadratic. Quadratic means that the function has the form $ax^2+bx+c$. Instead, that up-turning on the right is due to the exponential piece $2^x$.)

Comment: @march but i remember it has a name, i learned it in middle school but ive completely forgotten

Comment: I mean, it's possible that your instructor gave it their own name, but generally, out there in the world, there's no special name for such a function.

Comment: ah ok. sorry for waste of time

Comment: Do you know where this function is coming from? Maybe there is a reason why one would plot such a function, and therefore the name might be associated with that

Comment: @Andrei No, it was an exercise in which we plotted a graph by hand without knowing what it would look like or what it was.